# Cannot get SKSpriteNode's centerRect property to work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, stretch

It is simple. I set my sprite's centerRect as described in Apple Documentation but the image it displays gets distorted (as I hadn't defined centerRect property). My code:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ImageName")
sprite.centerRect = CGRect(x: 0.49, y: 0.49, width: 0.02, height: 0.02)
sprite.scale(to:CGSize(width: myCustomWidth, height: myCustomHeight))
//sprite.size = CGSize(width: myCustomWidth, height: myCustomHeight)
```

I don't know where did I make a mistake or whether it is something missing in my code.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOl9h.png)

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCSxH.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem. Actually it was about how scale(to:) method and size property works.

My problem was about how myCustomWidth and myCustomHeight were defined from the size property. These values belong to interval ((0,0),(0,0)) to ((1,1),(1,1)) so I was telling the computer to shrink the image. Therefore the centerRect property could not be applied since the image wasn’t enlarged.
So with values greater than image size in scale function and setting the actual size property to get the desired size on screen the problem was solved.

Now I’ll explain it in depth:

The size property changes your sprite’s size distorting your image if you don’t keep the same proportion between height and width.

The scale(to:) method uses the centerRect property to scale the node. If the result after the scale being applied is greater than the original image, it will use centerRect to scale without distorting the corners. Otherwise it could change sprite size **without** applying centerRect at all!

If your image is greater than the space you want the sprite to cover you can apply scale first and then resize (size property) preserving the proportion.

For any doubts, (or corrections) I would be pleased to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the width and height are, the counterpart should distort. The center part is only 2% * 2% of the image and is the major zooming part during the scale operations.

You can image the four corners will not change, so the center part can distort a lot if scale to (2X * 2X) of the original image , i.e. from (0.02 * 0.02 -> 1.02 * 1.02), that's more than 2500 times distortion in the center of image.

Your code has no problem.

Till now, the concept is correct. If you cannot get what you want, probably is the size of your original image size.

```
sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ImageName")
print (sprite.texture?.size()) // If size is very large here, then you cannot get what you want. The size of image should be small than target.  Actually only when you zoom in the texture, i.e, the current size is smaller than CGSize(width: myCustomWidth, height: myCustomHeight), you may get the result.

sprite.centerRect = CGRect(x: 0.49, y: 0.49, width: 0.02, height: 0.02)
sprite.scale(to:CGSize(width: myCustomWidth, height: myCustomHeight))
sprite.size = CGSize(width: myCustomWidth, height: myCustomHeight)
```

The last part is my testing code.

```
 class TestViewController: UIViewController{


        @IBOutlet weak var skview: SKView!

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode()
            sprite1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "round.png")
            print (sprite1.texture?.size())
            sprite1.centerRect = CGRect(x: 0.49, y: 0.49, width: 0.02, height: 0.02)
            print (sprite1.size)
            sprite1.scale(to:CGSize(width: 300, height:100))
            sprite1.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
            print (sprite1)
            skview.scene?.addChild(sprite1)
        }}
```

[image]

Comment: My problem is about the corners, which are distorted ( I am sorry if I didn’t express myself clearly). The image is solid coloured, so no distortion noticeable in the center.

Comment: There should be no change in the four corner. But one dimension zooming at the middle of four sides. You can call it distortion.

Comment: It’s better show the image. So people can know what the distortion is

Comment: What I get is like the sample image in Apple Developer Documentation as centerRect was not applied but changed scale. My image is a rounded corner square.

Comment: It’s supposed to be like this. If the original is a round shape

Comment: I think you misunderstood me

Comment: I think I found your expectation and the reason why it is not what you want.

Comment: It’s not the image size, I reduced it but no change. Even though it didn’t work I found that I should use scale property instead of size

Comment: In my case, If my picture is 1800x1800 pixels, I got the same wrong result. Then I shrink the image to 60 x 60. Now everything is stretched right as you want.

Comment: My first image was 512 px, and I shrunk it to 28 px but no change

Comment: The myCustomWidth and myCustomHeight  should be larger than 28. maybe like 100.

Comment: I added my test code. Let me know if it still not working.